# Attitude towards being close to others

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, psychology

What does one call the desire not to be too close to other people, and further, the aversion against that - on the street, on the beach, in public transportation, etc?

(What is considered "too close" may well depend on culture and the individual.)

**Edit:** This is an example of a "gapped sentence":

> CO<sub>2</sub> emissions are too high because too many people in
>   northern countries go to work with their own car. This is partially due to a
>   stronger [*desire not to be (too) close to other people*] than in
>   southern countries.

I admit that one could rephrase this by "due to a desire for more interpersonal space" or "due to a stronger desire for interpersonal space" - but that's what my question is about: Is there a single word for "desire for interpersonal space". A pathological form of this desire might be some kind of "social [claustrophobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claustrophobia)"

Comment: I've found 'ungregariousness' in one source, but won't put it in an answer as the source isn't one I'm familiar with.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Thanks for [gregariousness/sociality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociality)! It almost hits the nail on the head, and it's only the _spatial_ aspect that's somehow missing. But sociality has to do with some (abstract) vicinity - so  much is for sure.

Comment: 'body space' is the usual English term for the space people tend to keep from each other. 'Wider body space' would be easily understood.

Comment: @Mitch: Thanks for improving my question.

Answer (score 4):

In psychology, it has been called ***[body buffer zone](https://dictionary.apa.org/body-buffer-zone)*** and ***[interpersonal space](https://dictionary.apa.org/interpersonal-distance)***

> Some people have a larger buffer zone (or prefer more/larger
>   interpersonal space).

Comment: That's the word for what is preferred. But what about the preference itself?

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker Would you put it in a gapped sentence, please?

Comment: @SilverFace: Have done so.

Comment: I found two phobias that might be of use here: Demophobia
and Enochlophobia

Comment: Ochlophobia seems to be slightly more common (as a word).

Comment: @SilverFace What is a 'gapped' sentence? A sentence with a pause?

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker I've never heard of 'ochlophobia'. 'Agoraphobia' is the much much more common technical term (though it covers a broader range of behaviors). 'Claustrophobia' and 'agoraphobia' while nominally distinct are usually considered by psychiatrists to be closely related.

Comment: @Mitch https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/161934/80873

Comment: @SilverFace Oh OK. Having never heard that usage before, and not being a teacher of ESL, it sounds really strange to me (or maybe it is British English?). A gap is not the same as a blank to me (which is what I would call the empty slot. I'd call the sentence a 'template' where you're supposed to 'fill in the blanks'.